# Finding matching filenames between directories

Tags: python

What is the best way to find matching filenames between directories in python?

Comment: This isn't enough information to offer a good opinion on.

Comment: What did you try that wasn't good enough?

Comment: How much more specific could this be?  Yes, there are likely multiple ways (as with most questions) but Ashwini seemed to find a perfectly reasonable and concise answer.  Not to mention, this was the first result on my first attempt to find exactly this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
folder1={x for x in os.listdir('some_directory') if os.path.isfile(x)}
folder2={x for x in os.listdir('some_other_directory') if os.path.isfile(x)}
common_files=folder1.intersection(folder2)
```